# Bug (cache?) in WSO2 PDP when policy is created via Admin Services API

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I created a demo to demonstrates a problem (cache?) in PDP API on WSO2 IS.

My demo creates a policy and two tests to validate, and result OK (first test PERMIT and second DENY)

On first run, the results are displayed correctly (OK).

Via Carbon web interface, I delete all policies in PAP (and PDP), and ran again my Python demo, and the result is wrong (two tests result DENY).

My demo (see the README file for environment and configuration details):
https://github.com/welkson/WSO2-PDP-CacheTest

I've tried to disable caching of WSO2, but had no effect.

Tested with WSO2 IS 5.3 and 5.4.0-alpha2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its the same issue as that is reported 
in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5603. I have increased the priority so that this will be addressed in the next immediate release.

You can follow up with JIRA for the the progress of the fix.

Possible Workaround:

Clear the cache using the EntitlementAdminService
https://localhost:9443/services/EntitlementService?wsdl

Follow [1] to get an idea on how to invoke admin services.

Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xsd:clearPolicyCache/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Entitlement+using+SOAP+Service

Comment: Will it possible for you to do SOAP Admin Service Calls to the nodes?
If so we have a workaround

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @WelksonRenny updated the answer with a possible workaround.

Comment: Great! You might have to clear the decision cache as well.

Comment: at times the cache is still in the way, and only solves by clicking "Policy Finder Extensions -> Registry Policy Finder Module -> Refresh" via Carbon interface. Which SOAP method is executed when you click the refresh of the "Registry Policy Finder Module"?

Comment: As I said it might be due to decision cache. Can you do a policyCache and decisionCache together and see if it behaves in expected way.